# How to create fast functions based on units?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, units, upvalues

**Using units** is a good means for **rapidly developing code**, since it provides some error control.

Hovewer, using Mathamatica functions containing units appears to be **copmutationally inefficient**.

**Example**: I have a function:

```
LambdaSpeed[t_] := Quantity[10, "Nanometers"]/t
```

It gives some dimensional output for dimensional input, which I would like to plot in units of $c$:

```
Plot[LambdaSpeed[Quantity[t, "Seconds"]]/
   Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], {t, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

Effectively, plotting a hyperbola in chosen units takes **6.3 seconds** on my machine.

The problem is that Mathematica applies the same costly operation of unit conversion many times.

In developing I sometimes end up developing code in dimensional form and then redefining the same functions, assuming a chosen unit system.

**Question**: Is there a way to use functions containing units in high-performance calculations?

I would imagine this would require defining automatic rules, which would call an interpreter for each given unit conversion just once and the rest would be evaluated directly without interpreter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the option `Evaluated->True` or wrapping the first argument of `Plot` with `Evaluated` gives a 100x speed-up:

```
ls1[t_] := Quantity[10, "Nanometers"]/t
Plot[ls1[Quantity[t, "Seconds"]]/Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], {t, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

[image]

```
ls2[t_] := Quantity[10, "Nanometers"]/t
Plot[ls2[Quantity[t, "Seconds"]]/Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], {t, 0, 10}, 
     Evaluated -> True] // Timing
```

[image]

```
ls3[t_] := Quantity[10, "Nanometers"]/t
Plot[Evaluate[ls3[Quantity[t, "Seconds"]]/Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]], 
    {t, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

[image]

**Update:** Better yet, define the function to be plotted outside `Plot` wrapped with `Evaluate`:

```
ls4[t_] := Evaluate[Quantity[10, "Nanometers"]/Quantity[t, "Seconds"]/
   Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]]

Plot[ls4[t], {t, 0, 10}] // Timing
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is even nicer than I would have hoped for, thousand of thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.